Should a clickable card have a tooltip about what happen when clicked? (Desktop SaaS App)
Context: a SaaS application in which users manage their projects. They mostly need to keep the status of the project updated, see the project information, and write notes if something comes up. Mainly used on desktop.
The main page is the list of all the active projects. Here there is a table and a card view available. In the table view, we have a button at the end of the row to open more details (it is a new page):

For the card view, the whole card is clickable. These created to two questions:

Should a clickable card here also shown a tooltip on hover? Why / Why not?
If yes, should the tooltip appear on top of the card like it does with other elements (but then it looks very distant to the cursor) or should be just for this case appear next to the cursor?



How does someone access this tooltip information if they're using a touch device / keyboard?

The tooltip is shown on focus when navigating on a keyboard. On mobile they are not available - user will use this platform mostly on desktop, and although we are creating mobile friendly layouts the tooltips are not going part of it (they should also never contain essential information, so the idea is that they are going to support the user on desktop to learn the meaning of the icon-only buttons)

Tooltip

A message which appears when a cursor is positioned over an icon, image, hyperlink, or other element in a graphical user interface.

In the definition, the tooltip is used for simple and unique elements. A card is usually a set of elements, where each of them can have its own tooltip.
I would leave the tooltips for these basic interactive elements. For a card I would opt for a hover effect with a text.


Many sites that have icon buttons allow the user to see a toggle to get more information about the task to perform if the button is pressed, take this site as an example.


For the icons in your example, I think the chevron does not help to identify that see details is the task to perform there. It seems that you're on a cascade process and if you click the chevron you continue with the process. I suggest you change the icon to give more context.

And for the card Danielillo's answer is the best approach, also have in mind that if the user uses the keyboard to jump between the elements you should use focus to use that interaction.
